# What's a good way to generate Excel reports from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've tried [`sp_makewebtask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238843%28SQL.80%29.aspx) but it is very limited. I need something much more flexible. i.e. Generate Excel files with multiple sheets/tabs.

Answer (score 2):

After spending a good few years developing SSRS reports, I am now using the excellent NPOI libraries.

http://npoi.codeplex.com/

This was borne out of two things.

1) The first thing my users ever do with an SSRS report is export to Excel.
2) I had no control over how SSRS exported to Excel.

The libraries come with an example solution which give decent examples of how to achieve many common tasks.  It is also very performant.

This requires some **.NET programming knowledge**, an IDE able to create programs, but if you have the experience, and are okay with only being able to generate files to the Excel 2003 format, cannot recommend NPOI highly enough.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more... 'default'? I have limited access to the server, so I can't install anything.

Comment: I am not aware of anything that'll give you the level of control you're after "out of the box".

Comment: Is the reverse possible? Using Excel macros to get data from SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Like Paul said, without being able to install anything on the server, you won’t have much luck, but if you can install something on the server you could use OfficeWriter.

OfficeWriter does a great job of this. It can create files in both the .XLS file format as well as the .XLSX file format.   It will let you generate full-featured Excel reports. Such as multiple worksheets, formulas, conditional formats etc.

OfficeWriter integrates nicely into SSRS, it even has a designer for end users to build, edit and publish reports from within Microsoft Office, no programming knowledge needed to use the designer.
You can read OfficeWriter’s integration with SSRS at http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-for-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx

Disclaimer: 
I work for the company that makes OfficeWriter.